Relation of the colour of my score and the number of up votes
I asked a question on physics stack exchange. I got a notification that there is a -40 (minus forty) score added to me. However there are 4 positive ticks that is four upvotes. I don't understand. I request someone to please clarify this.

You spent 50 reputation to start the bounty, and afterward you got 1 upvote. That's a total of $-40$. (In general, you only get notifications about reputation when something good happens, which is why you didn't immediately see "$-50$" when you set the bounty.)
